# Is it necessary to block googlebot and googlebot-video to block video crawl?

Tags: googlebot, robots.txt, rich-snippets, video

We have problem with declining CTR caused by unwanted video snippet on SERP. Therefore we have taken measure to block the Googlebot from crawling our video file.

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*.mp4$
```

However, still many of our pages got this video snippet.

1. Does Googlebot-video need to be blocked as well?
2. Why is it mentioned here Googlebot and Googlebot-video for user agent tokens for Googlebot Video (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en)?
   Does it mean both can be used interchangeably for blocking any video result? (Blocking Googlebot means also removing result from video search?)

Comment: Are there any crawlers you want downloading videos?   Maybe use `User-Agent: *`

Comment: might be a little bit overkill. Just want to know what exactly does Googlebot and Googlebot-video crawl for, so I can apply appropriate directive. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: 1) Do you mean their [video rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video)? 2) Do you provide the Schema.org structured data?

Comment: 1. Yes. like [this](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/53/file-29103626-png/video-google-rich-snippet.png?t=1528511404751&width=580&name=video-google-rich-snippet.png)
2. No. as we don't want to give more video "signal" to Google

Comment: Why not check your server logs to see which bots access the videos.

Comment: Tony McCreath, good approach!

Comment: @TonyMcCreath Good approach. Thanks.
So having Googlebot blocked means it shouldn't be able to crawl my video OR it will still crawl except won't take my video content into consideration?

Comment: The disallow is a request for them to not crawl. The video may be considered for indexing. e.g. Google knows their is a video on the page and their may be mark up to tell Google what the video is about, and a thumbnail. That may be enough for them to still show it in search.